# empty $_POST in PHP mail()

Tags: php, forms, session

Some help with the following would be greatly appreciated! I've been searching the web and stackoverflow for hours. There is this problem with my php mail function.

There's a form on my website (the site uses wordpress) with two text fields, name and phone number. There's also a hidden field in the form that displays the current url, so we can see on what page the form was filled in. This information is also stored in a php session.

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
?> 

<form name="callback" action="callme.php" method="post" onsubmit="return(validate());">
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" size=15 />
<label>Tel:</label><input class="sky" type="text" name="tel" size=15 />
<div id="afterfive"><p>Call after five<input type="checkbox" name="afterfive" value="Call back after five"></p></div>
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['url']; ?>">
<input type="submit" class="classname" value="Call me back!" title="Call me back!" />
</form>

<script>
function validate()
{
if( document.callme.name.value == "" )
{
 alert( "Please fill in your name" );
 document.callme.name.focus() ;
 return false;
 }
if( document.callme.tel.value == "" )
{
alert( "Please fill in your phone number" );
document.callme.tel.focus() ;
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

The following php code is callme.php:

```
<?php session_start();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$afterfive = $_POST['afterfive']; 
$url = $_POST['url'];

$to = "me@myemail.com";
$subject = "Please call back $name";
$message .= "Hi, the following person would like to be called back: \n";
$message .= "Name: $name \n";
$message .= "Phonenumber: $tel \n";
$message .= "$afterfive \n";
$message .= "This message was send from this page: $url \n";
$headers = "From: meagain@myemail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: meagain@myemail.com" . "\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['tel'] = $_POST['tel'];
header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.thankyou");
}

?>
```

After submitting the form, the visitor is redirected to our thankyou page and given the opportunity the fill in additional information using a second form. The information previously stored in the php session (form fields name, tel and url) are added in hidden form fields.

This all works fine most of the time, but sometimes we receive e-mails with all or some fields empty. Of course this could be users with javascript disabled or google bots that submit blank forms, but the weird thing is that sometimes even the url field is empty (the form is not visible on our homepage). Shouldn't $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] always still work?

I was thinking about adding php form validation, but I'm not sure this will solve the problem. Could this have something to do with the hyper cache plug-in for wordpress? Or could it be related to the php session?

Comment: What happens if someone loads `callme.php` directly in the browser? It will run the code, and neither $_POST and $_SESSION will contain anything.

Comment: *"but sometimes we receive e-mails with all or some fields empty"* - You should be using a server-side method such as `if(empty($_POST['name'])){ die("You need to enter your name.");` etc. and that will ensure that the fields you wish to be NOT empty, be filled. In conjunction with what `Andrewsi` mentioned, use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` at the top of your handler, and name your submit button to `name="submit"` that way the `callme.php` if accessed directly, won't process the information without the submit button being clicked.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of that. But loading it directly does return an empty email. Could this be google bots loading the page or could this have something to do with hyper cache plug-in? I find it weird that we sometimes receive as much as 4 empty e-mails in one hour...

Comment: @user2932451 Use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` on top of `$name = $_POST['name'];` and close it with a brace at the end, and that will ensure against that, as mentioned in my comment. You're welcome.

Comment: @user2932451 Have a look at what I posted below as an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"but sometimes we receive e-mails with all or some fields empty"*

You should be using a server-side method instead of JS such as

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])){ die("You need to enter your name.");
```

*(**JS** can always be disabled by the user, one probable cause for empty emails/fields)*

and that will ensure that the fields you wish to be NOT empty, be filled. In conjunction with what [Andrewsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662201/empty-post-in-php-mail/19662824#comment29198019_19662201) mentioned, use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` at the top of your handler, and name your submit button to `name="submit"` that way the `callme.php` if accessed directly, won't process the information without the submit button being clicked.

### For example:

**Note:** There are many other ways to achieve this, but this is a basic yet effective method.

Naming your submit button such as:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

in your case, it would be:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="classname" value="Call me back!" title="Call me back!" />
```

PHP handler

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(empty($_POST['name'])){ die("You need to enter your name."); }
    if(empty($_POST['tel'])){ die("You need to enter your telephone number."); }
    if(empty($_POST['afterfive'])){ die("You need to fill this field."); }
    if(empty($_POST['url'])){ die("You need to fill this field."); }

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $afterfive = $_POST['afterfive']; 
    $url = $_POST['url'];

    $to = "me@myemail.com";
    $subject = "Please call back $name";
    $message .= "Hi, the following person would like to be called back: \n";
    $message .= "Name: $name \n";
    $message .= "Phonenumber: $tel \n";
    $message .= "$afterfive \n";
    $message .= "This message was send from this page: $url \n";
    $headers = "From: meagain@myemail.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "BCC: meagain@myemail.com" . "\r\n";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION['tel'] = $_POST['tel'];
        header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.thankyou");
    }

}

// You could use this at end also to show a message
// if callme.php is accessed directly.
// else {echo "You cannot do that from here.";exit;}

?>
```

Comment: It seems to work. Haven't received any empty mails after implementing the above code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript refers to `document.callme`, but there is nothing in your code with that name.